# Affiliate links in Facebook app - Against app policy?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, policy

Not so much a techy question as a policy question.

When developing an app, are you allowed to show links provided from affiliates if it makes up part of your content? For example, an app that is specifically for finding vinyl of a specific genre, from Affiliate Window. Poor example, but in essence the policy usage is the same.

My main concern is this - https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ - Specifically III.E.2

Any pointers would be ace, thanks!

Comment: did you find an answer to this? Wondering the same thing

Comment: Nope, still pursuing other avenues! Will let you know if I find out =)

Answer (score 1):

According to III.E.2 you can only sell products or advertise products on this list: http://developers.facebook.com/adproviders/

Has anyone found any more info on this?